# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Sreams app in Spring Native / GraalVM image

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-native

I've compiled my app containing a Kafka Streams stream with maven `-Pnative` native profile and start it with `-Dspring.aot.enabled=true -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`, but the start fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaStreamsFunctionBeanPostProcessor': class org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition cannot be cast to class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition (org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition and org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition are in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @7daf6ecc)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArgument(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:334)
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition cannot be cast to class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition (org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition and org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition are in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @7daf6ecc)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.function.KafkaStreamsFunctionBeanPostProcessor.extractResolvableTypes(KafkaStreamsFunctionBeanPostProcessor.java:174)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.function.KafkaStreamsFunctionBeanPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(KafkaStreamsFunctionBeanPostProcessor.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Any ideas what might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not supported yet by Spring Cloud Stream https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2323.

Comment: Is there an update or timeline for this that can be added for future searchers?